# $wpdb->update prefixes database name to table when executing query

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I run into a problem I can't seem to fix. I went back and forth and even used $wpdb->prepare() and $wpdb->query() functions, nothing helps.

$table_prefix."users" returns wp_2qttgdv7ac_2_users (slightly changed for security purposes)

```
$wpdb->update($table_prefix."users", array('user_email' => $fetch_data['new_email']), array('user_login' => $fetch_data['username']))
```

This was not working, but on running...

```
var_dump( $wpdb->last_error)
```

I get the error:

> string(59) "Table 'A41K421094D3615.wp_2qttgdv7ac_2_users' doesn't exist"

Here *A41K421094D3615* is the database name. I am running in a multisite environment. However, accessing custom tables does not add database name in front of the table. How can I get it to stop adding it? Or at least make it honor the table. Usually database_name.table_name should work, right? However, it's returning that it does not exist. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->prefix . "users", 
        array('user_email' => $fetch_data['new_email']), 
        array('user_login' => $fetch_data['username'])
);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried $wpdb->prefix as well. Same result.